# Excel 2011 for Mac: Compile error on line that should not be compiling

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook for both Windows & Mac.  One platform on the Mac I want it to run on is Excel 2011.

My workbook uses a custom Ribbon tab.  Sometimes, depending on what the user does, I want the text of the ribbon buttons to change.  So I have code that does this.

I know that a custom Ribbon tab is not possible in Excel 2011.  That is okay.  However, there is a line in my code that is giving me a compile error on that version of Excel.  I thought I had it set that it would not compile the code if running on this version of Excel, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am defining a variable of type IRibbonUI for use inside a standard module.  (The module is Module3, and it is dedicated to code having to do with the Ribbon.)  I wrap the variable definition code (along with the rest of the code in this module) in an #IF statement, like so:

```
#If Not Mac or MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >=15 Then

    Dim ribbonUI As IRibbonUI

    ... rest of the code in Module3 ...

#End If
```

This means it should not compile at run-time on Excel 2011.

When the workbook opens, I do not get any errors.  However, when I am running a sub (let's call it "UpdateOptions", and it is in Module1) that calls a sub that changes the Ribbon (let's call that one "ChangeRibbon", which is in Module3*), I get a compile error on the ribbonUI line: User-defined type not defined

I don't understand why, because as far as I understand, the code in that module shouldn't be compiling at run-time.

*ChangeRibbon should never actually be run on Excel 2011.  I have an IF statement that makes sure it is not, like so:

```
Sub UpdateOptions()

... some code ...

#If Not Mac or MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >=15 Then
    Module3.ChangeRibbon
End If

... some other code ...

End Sub
```

When I step through the code, the error happens when UpdateOptions is first called by another sub.  The step-through highlights the name of the sub as the line that is causing the error:

```
Sub UpdateOptions()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried seperating the if clause into seperate ones?

Comment: And have you tried printing the value of the statement to the debug window.

Comment: I tried putting the line 'Dim ribbonUI As IRibbonUI' into it's own #IF statement, but that didn't fix it.  Which value are you suggesting I print to the debug window?

Comment: Test what `Mac` and `MAC_OFFICE_VERSION` return. If it is compiled then it means the IF clause is somehow entered. Then the other thing that may (but really shouldn't) be causing an Issue is the ordern in which OR and NOT are evaluated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence). By separating/nesting the IF clause you can trace exactly  where the evaluation goes wrong.

Comment: Posted an answer with some examples for you to try out. In the second codeblock you can also plug in `Mac` and `MAC_OFFICE_VERSION` instead of `A` and `B` to see if the result is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post it as an answer since it won't fit into the comment section.

It seems that you enter your code, even thought it should not. The easiest explanation is, that your if statement is not evaluated properly. You should check the values of `Mac` and `MAC_OFFICE_VERSION`, this should already show you what went wrong. Another reason could be that you made a wrong assumption about how VBA evaluates logic clauses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence

If you split/nest the the If-Block it is easier to see which evaluation goes wrong:

```
Public Sub testVer()
    #If Not Mac Then
        Debug.Print "Not a Mac"
    #Else
        #If MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 Then
            Debug.Print "Mac Version equal or above 15: ", MAC_OFFICE_VERSION
        #Else
            Debug.Print "Mac Version below 15: ", MAC_OFFICE_VERSION
        #End If
    #End If
End Sub
```

Here is a small example to see how your if clause gets evaluated:
In VBA the clause `Not A Or B` is the same as `(Not A) Or B`, so maybe you just mixed up logic.

```
Sub testOrNot()

    printNotAOrB True, True
    printNotAOrB True, False
    printNotAOrB False, True
    printNotAOrB False, False


End Sub

Private Sub printNotAOrB(A As Boolean, B As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "A = " & A, "B = " & B
    Debug.Print "Not A Or B  :", Not A Or B
    Debug.Print "Not (A Or B):", Not (A Or B)
    Debug.Print "(Not A) Or B:", (Not A) Or B
    Debug.Print
End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at here.  But before I saw this answer, I figured out how to "fake out" Excel 2011 into thinking I had defined custom data types, and that solved the problem.  I'll post that as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the thought of if I could possibly "fake out" Excel 2011 into thinking I had created a custom data type for IRibbonUI (and, as it turned out, I had to do it for another type, too) and that worked.  In my module dealing with all my Ribbon code, I put this at the top:

```
#If Mac And MAC_OFFICE_VERSION < 15 Then

Type IRibbonUI
    ribbontype As String
End Type

Type IRibbonControl
    ribboncontrol As String
End Type

#End If
```

I no longer receive the compile error.

In regards to L8n's answer, I don't believe the logic of the IF statement was a problem.  I had also tried calling on a Function I created long ago to test if the version of Excel was Excel 2011 for Mac.  So my IF statement started like this:

```
#IF ExcelForMac2011 = False Then
```

I know my function works properly, because I call it many other times in my workbook, and it has always worked correctly.  So I don't think it was a logic problem in the IF statement.  I think this was a bug in Excel 2011.  Unfortunately, it has MANY, MANY bugs.